# move a column across a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to move the last column (ID) of a data.frame as first, how do I take care of removing from the last position?. I would like to keep 1:length(df)

```
df.1 <- subset(df, select=c(ID,1:length(df)))
```

Because of 1:length(df) my code duplicate the ID as last column. My attempt was:

```
df.1 <- subset(df, select=c(ID,1:length(df-1)))
```

which is wrong. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We subset the last column using `ncol(df)`, and all other columns except the last one `-ncol(df)`, and `cbind`.

```
df.1 <- cbind(df[ncol(df)], df[-ncol(df)])
```

Or even without `cbind`ing, we concatenate the column indexes to move the last column to the front.

```
df.1 <- df[c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))]
```

Or we can subset by using the column names.  As 'ID' was mentioned as the last column.  We concatenate the 'ID' and all other column names except the 'ID' using `setdiff` to move the last column.

```
df.1 <- df[c('ID',setdiff(names(df), 'ID'))]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 5*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
df$ID <- 1:6
```